# Errors when running AngularJS test for submodule

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

Decided to break app into submodules

Main app is "myApp", then I have a submodule called "myApp.users" that has its own directives and services.  One of the services holds the users resource model.  Trying to write tests, but keep getting error.

error

`Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: userServiceProvider <- userService`

Code

```
'use strict';

describe('Service: userService', function () {

  // load the service's module
  beforeEach(function(){
    module('myApp.users');
  });

  // instantiate service
  var userService;
  beforeEach(inject(function (_ userService_) {
    userService = _ userService_;
  }));

  it('should do something', function () {
    expect(!!userService).toBe(true);
  });

});
```

Comment: You have an extra space `_ userService_`. I have a similar issue though.